# Google+ OAuth authorizaton error (invalid token)

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, google-plus

On Google+ I need to access the user's timeline.
I use the following code to authenticate:

```
private string GetUrl(string url, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {
            if (parameters.Count == 0)
            {
                return url;
            }

            string query_string = String.Empty;
            foreach (var k in parameters)
                query_string += k.Key + "=" + (k.Value) + "&";

            query_string = query_string.TrimEnd('&');

            return url + "?" + query_string;
        }

var req = GetUrl(auth_endpoint, new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "response_type", "code" },
                { "client_id", "XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com" },
                { "redirect_uri", "http://localhost:58772/GooglePlus.aspx" },
                { "scope", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me" },
                { "state", "authenticated" },
            });

            Response.Redirect(req);
```

But when I request the https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo API using the 'Authorization: Bearer XXXX' header, I get the following error.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "com.google.auth",
    "reason": "invalidAuthentication",
    "message": "invalid token",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "invalid token"
 }
}
```

The same happens using 'curl' to make the request.
I copied and pasted the authentication code given by google lots of time... same result. The authentication code looks like this: 4/XXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXX

How can I solve?
Thank you

Comment: Why are you adding ".apps.googleusercontent.com" to the client ID?

Comment: The authorization code you received from google can only be used once. Can you use the https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=INSERT_ACCESS_TOKEN API to see if your access token is valid?

Answer (score 0):

This could happen because of wrong url being used for validating token. Had same problem. Try with this url :- `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=<token>` . Hope it helps.